# Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I am trying to configure Bluetooth PAN on raspberry in order to be able to access it over bluetooth from android ssh client. I was following [tutorial](http://www.penguintutor.com/blog/viewpost.php?id=wp6392). All works fine until the command `sdptool get Lan` that gives me `Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This might help

[sdptool is broken in Bluez 5](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201672)

You need to run the blue tooth daemon in compatibility mode to provide deprecated command line interfaces. You're running Bluez5 and you need some Bluez4 functions. You can do this by editing this file

```
/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service
```

and changing this line

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

to this

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat`

and then restarting bluetooth like this

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

and you'll also have to change permissions on `/var/run/sdp`

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/sdp
```

Comment: Huh. This seems to have still fixed bluetooth A2DP sink on my box. It's 2 years later...

Comment: Solved my issue :D `bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (2, 'No such file or directory')`

Comment: This also fixes the same issue on Debian (desktop).

Comment: This edit gets reverted when Blue Z get's updated.  Is this ever going to be permanently fixed?  Is there a better workaround?

Comment: This fix stopped working on `2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf.img`. Could RaspberryPi and Debian PLEEEZE get their sh*t together on this? A bot closed the GitHub issue for this bug

Comment: life saver. THANK YOU