# sdp_connect always fails

Tags: bluetooth

I am running a sample code on RPI Zero W and it gets to the point where sdp_connect happens. Tried different samples, but they all fail on the same codeline:

```
session = sdp_connect( BDADDR_ANY, BDADDR_LOCAL, SDP_RETRY_IF_BUSY );

if (!session) {
   printf("sdp_connect failed");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to enable bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be due to the fact that *bluetoothd* wasn't launched with *--compat* option.

Take a look at [Registering a sdp service with bluez on Fedora 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739906/registering-a-sdp-service-with-bluez-on-fedora-20) for further details.

Feel free to ignore the Fedora environment referenced in the linked answer. Using or not using Fedora is not important. Launching it with *--compat* or *-C* will enable the backward compatibility and I expect that *sdp_connect()* will works. I pasted a link that should provide a more deeply explanation about the issue and how to solve it, in general. The result is to add a simple option to the startup of *bluetoothd* as I did on my RPi board.

Comment: Does the OP use **Fedora 20** on his Raspberry Pi? You should explain more details if it also fit to a RasPi.

Comment: @Ingo apologize me if I was too much short in my answer, but, I think that using or not using Fedora is not important here. The issue was related to bluetoothd daemon that wasn't launched with --compat option. Launching it with --compat or -C will enable the backward compatibility and I expect that sdp_connect() will works. Further, I pasted a link that should provide a more deeply explanation about the issue and how to solve it, in general. Of course, I expect that the end user is able to add a simple option to the startup of bluetoothd in the raspberry pi as I did on my RPi board.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the bluetooth daemon in compatibility mode

1. Edit this file

```
/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service
```

2. Change this line

ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

with this line

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat
```

3. Restart bluetooth

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

See this link for more details: [Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/failed-to-connect-to-sdp-server-on-ffffff000000-no-such-file-or-directory)